# finding file size for a conditional

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to write a conditional statement so that if a file is greater than 1GB it prints the name of that file, in a file, and skips processing it.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.dmp
do
    if [ ! $(stat -c %s $f > 1000000000) ]; then
        name=`basename ${f%.dmp}`
        if [ -f ../tshark/$name.dat ]; then
            echo "file exists, moving on...";
        else
            echo "Processing" $name;
            tshark -PVx -r "$f" > ../tshark/$name.dat;
            echo $name "complete, moving on...";
        fi
    else
        echo $f "too large";
        echo $f "\n" > tooLarge.txt;
    fi
done
```

The problem is `! $(stat -c %s $f > 1000000000)` isn't working.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you haven't seen the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html), you should. Yes, it's focused around Bash, but it's also a great reference for things like this conditional.

Now, what you've written tries to execute `stat -c %s $f > 1000000000` as a command (it's inside the parens on the `$()` construct, which is equivalent to the old backtick, as far as I understand. What you want is `$(stat -c %s $f) -le 1000000000` which does `stat -c %s $f` and then checks if it's less than or equal to `1000000000`. This (i.e., `a<=b`) is the [equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Logical_equivalence) of `!(a>b)` logically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is "! $(stat -c %s $f > 1000000000)" isn't working.

You are including the condition in your *command*, i.e. within $(...). Say:

"! $(stat -c %s $f) > 1000000000"